# Formating a single textfield so that it display is different to all the others

Tags: ios, localization, formatting, uitextfield, uiapplicationdelegate

How would i set the currency in a text field to display it as a localized currency, with a leading 0. If someone types in 16.25  pence it would be formated as 0.1625£ respectively. I am using delegation and formating all text fields so only numbers can be passed in, this field should also be localized.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range     replacementString:(NSString *)string  {    // First, create the text that will end up in the     input field if you'll return YES:
    NSString *resultString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range    withString:string];
    // Now, validate the text and return NO if you don't like what it'll contain.
// You accomplish this by trying to convert it to a number and see if that worked.
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
   [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSNumber* resultingNumber = [numberFormatter numberFromString:resultString];
    //[numberFormatter release];
    return resultingNumber != nil;
```

I do not want this to change, as it formats all my fields. Just want textField1 to have the relevant format,how would i go about doing this, i think it lies in viewdidload method and setting the text property to be localized to a floating point, but i cant seem to work out how to do it.

Comment: Its kind of hard to tell what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField

{
    if (textfield1) {

```
    NSString *txt = self.textfield1.text;

    double num1 = [txt doubleValue];


    double tCost = num1 /100;





    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];


    NSString *numberAsString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:tCost]];


    self.textfield1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",numberAsString];
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which textField you want to format in the delegate method above.

```
if (textField == textField1) {

   // Do Something....

} else {

  // Do whatever you want with the other text fields

}
```

For floating point formatting, use something like this -

```
[myTextField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", myFloat]];
```

Comment: [textfield1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", myFloat]];
i have managed to get the if else statement working, but how would i incorporate the above line of code for textfield one, as i understood the delegate method returns a nil if a character other then text is returned. But i need it to return a not nill and a formated string.

Comment: I tried doing this.. way off right ..             [resultString setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", (float)resultingNumber]];  i recieved a could not cast pointer with float.

Comment: ive worked out my own way to do it :) using - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField